# Getting "null" in result

Tags: php, android, listview

I am trying to use `listView` with images using php. I am retriving data from table and getting null in my `'result'` and `'is '` variable however my `PHP` code is working fine.I don't understand what is the problem After the splash screen application is crashes. Here is the code of my `listview`

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mylist);

        listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lsview);
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy((new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitNetwork().build()));
        collectData();
        CustomListView customListView=new CustomListView(this,name,details,images);
        listView.setAdapter(customListView);


    }

    private void collectData() {
        HttpURLConnection con = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(urladdress);
            con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            con.setRequestMethod("GET");

            is = new BufferedInputStream(con.getInputStream());


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            con.disconnect();
        }
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");

            }
            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {


            JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(result);
            JSONObject jo = null;
            name = new String[ja.length()];
            details = new String[ja.length()];
            images = new String[ja.length()];

            for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {
                jo = ja.getJSONObject(i);
                name[i] = jo.getString("name");
                details[i] = jo.getString("email");
                images[i] = jo.getString("Images");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: have you give internet permission?

Comment: post logcat here also

Comment: Logcat will help to resolve your crash issue

Comment: have you used JSON array to get data to android from php?

Comment: Can you please give me the postman response of your Json

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
 private void collectData() {
    HttpURLConnection con = null;
    String result = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(urladdress);
        con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");

        is = new BufferedInputStream(con.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");

        }
        is.close();
        result = sb.toString();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        con.disconnect();
    }

    try {


        JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(result);
        JSONObject jo = null;
        name = new String[ja.length()];
        details = new String[ja.length()];
        images = new String[ja.length()];

        for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {
            jo = ja.getJSONObject(i);
            name[i] = jo.getString("name");
            details[i] = jo.getString("email");
            images[i] = jo.getString("Images");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Can you please add some comment as to why they should 'try this'.

Comment: fetch the result before you disconnect the connection

Answer (score 0):

Your app is crashing because of this line:-

CustomListView customListView=new CustomListView(this,name,details,images);

name, details and images are initialized only after network call is complete, but you are accessing them before that.

So, you should move this line to collectData() method, like this:-

```
onCreate(){
    listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lsview);
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy((new 
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitNetwork().build()));
    collectData();
}
```

---

```
private void collectData() {
    HttpURLConnection con = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(urladdress);
            con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            con.setRequestMethod("GET");

            is = new BufferedInputStream(con.getInputStream());


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            con.disconnect();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {

            JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(result);
            JSONObject jo = null;
            name = new String[ja.length()];
            details = new String[ja.length()];
            images = new String[ja.length()];

            for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {
                jo = ja.getJSONObject(i);
                name[i] = jo.getString("name");
                details[i] = jo.getString("email");
                images[i] = jo.getString("Images");
            }

        CustomListView customListView=new 
        CustomListView(this,name,details,images);
        listView.setAdapter(customListView);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```